# MIPS drum sequencer ends imediatly on MARS enviroment

Tags: assembly, mips, sequence, mars-simulator

I'm tryng to create a drum sequencer in MIPS I've stored in memory, with the directive ".word", 0 and 1 values. 1 means that the 1/16 of the 4/4 bar loop needs to be played. So register $t8 will adress the 16 words in memory where the program will control if the sound has to be played (1), or sleep (0). $t7 is a counter for verifying when the loop ends and the sequence has to be restarted. The problem is that when I assemble the program ( and MARS does it fine ) and run it, after one step of execution I obtain this message : "-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --" ok...but why ?!

Here is the source Code:

```
.data

LOOP1: .word 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0


    la $t8, LOOP1           #

    addi $t9, $t9, 0        #increments $t8 with the correct amount to adress every 1/16

    li $t2, 114             #sound's timbre

Loop:

    addiu $t8, $t8, $t9

    lw $t1, 0($t8)

    addi $t7, $t7, 1        #$t7 is used to verify the loop's end

    bne $0, $t1, PlaySound      

    li $a0, 100


    li $v0, 32

    syscall                    #sleep syscall

Afterplayng:

    sll $t9, $t9, 2

    beq $t7, 16, ReinitializeLoopCounter

        j Loop                #jumps back to the top of loop

PlaySound:

    li $a0, 62 

    li $a1, 100

    move $a2, $t2

    li $a3, 120

    la $v0, 33

    syscall                #calls service 33, playing music

    j Afterplayng

ReinitializeLoopCounter:

    addi $t7, $0, 1

    addi $t8, $t8, -64

    j Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code.
The first one is that you are not telling MARS whre your code begins.

You should add a line

```
.code
```

after this line:

```
LOOP1: .word 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
```

Then if you try to assembly MARS will show some errors, e.g. you are issuing `addiu $t8, $t8, $t9` which expects an immediate and not a register as the third argument.

There are other suspicious code there. For example one line at the beginning states

```
addi $t9, $t9, 0        #increments $t8 with the correct amount to adress every 1/16
```

but it really does nothing useful (adds constant 0 to $t9, which is not what your description says it would do).

If modified a little bit your code to test midi capabilities of MARS:

```
.data

LOOP1: .word 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0
.text

  la $t8, LOOP1           #

  li $t2, 114             #sound's timbre  ???
Loop:

  lw $t1, 0($t8)
  addiu $t8, $t8, 4  # Increment play data
  addi $t7, $t7, 1        #$t7 is used to verify the loop's end
  bne $0, $t1, PlaySound      
  li $a0, 100
  li $v0, 32
  syscall                    #sleep syscall
Afterplayng:
  beq $t7, 16, ReinitializeLoopCounter
  j Loop                #jumps back to the top of loop
PlaySound:
  li $a0, 62 
#  li $a1, 100
  li $a1, 500  # half second
  move $a2, $t2
  li $a3, 120
  la $v0, 33
  syscall                #calls service 33, playing music
  j Afterplayng
ReinitializeLoopCounter:
  addi $t7, $0, 1
  la $t8, LOOP1           # Reinitialize $t8
  j Loop
```

Check the differences with your code. This one just plays a sound, then pauses, etc according to the info stored from LOOP1

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, it's the first time I'm using MARS.
I've corrected the addiu $t8, $t8, $t9 error, and ".code";but it still ends immediatly

Comment: @user3689009: check the edited answer. I fiddled a bit with your code to test how MARS outputs MIDI samples.

Comment: thanks a lot, now the Loop sequence works fine, but I've a question:
Is there a method for playing multiple sounds simultaneously ?

Comment: @user3689009: I think mars does not support multiple sounds simultaneously as it only uses one MIDI channel. You are using syscall 33 which waits for the sound duration, so maybe you can try using multiple `syscall 31` and then wait using `syscall 32`, though i don't think it will work.